# Understanding variables in classes

Tags: class, variables

I'm new to programming and have what I'm sure is a simple question for anyone with experience.

Basically, I found this code from some other site that was trying to explain how classes work and there are parts of it that I don't understand. I'm going to post the code here. (If I'm not allowed to post code like this from other sites that are meant to help just let me know and I will remove it.)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Simple
{
private:
    int A;

public:
    Simple(int B)
    {
        SetID(B);
    }

    void SetID(int B) { A = B; }
    int GetID() { return A; }
};

int main()
{
    Simple cSimple(1);
    cSimple.SetID(2);
    std::cout << cSimple.GetID() << std::endl;
}
```

Ok, so I have a decent understanding of how classes work, however, in trying to understand this example I ran into what I assume are variable declarations immediately followed by (sorry if I get the wording wrong) parameters with arguments. For example, Simple *cSimple* is what appears to be an object that is being made from the *Simple* class, however, I'm not sure what the *(1)* immediately after is supposed to be doing. If someone could answer this for me, and also if you have the time and are feeling generous, give me a quick explanation of what this program in general is doing, I would be greatly appreciative. Thanks!

Comment: Some offtopic remarks: I will never use a capital letter as first letter in variable names. This since a class name starts with a capital. Second, I start my class members with d_ to recognise them as class members. Thirdly, I believe that the 'private' is not necessary since declarations in a class are by default private up to the public keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not well-versed in C++, but here it goes..

The 1 immediately after it is supposed to be the argument to the Simple(int B) function (it's called the constructor, by the way)

What this program is doing is this:
Simple cSimple(1) : calls the constructor, which calls the SetID function and sets A to be 1

cSimple.SetID(2): changes the value of A from 1 to 2

cSimple.GetID(): returns A, which is 2

Comment: I clicked the check mark and made it green, is that all I have to do?